# Skip first page in ADB2C password less authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, password-less

I am using passwordless authentication that uses OTP-based authentication.

I am entering the phone number and the second page is confirming the phone number and country code. I want to skip either the first or second page. As I am entering phone numbers as my input, I need a UserInputType to support phone number type.

**First Page**

[image]

**Confirmation Page**

[image]

**Verification code page**

[image]

Comment: Is it user flow or custom policy?

Comment: It is custom policy.